# How many ways are there to place $10$ different flags on $7$ different flagpoles if order matters and no flagpole is left empty?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to place $10$ different flags on $7$ different flagpoles if the order of the flags on a flagpole is relevant and every flagpole flies at least one flag?

The way I look at it is that if need at least $1$ flag for each one you can remove that from there so now you $3$ flags to put into $7$ flagpoles which is $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 =210$.

Comment: $765 =210$  What?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 = 210$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let us assume that the flags are identical and then we can multiply the solution by $10!$ for each arrangement.

The number of ways of distributing $10$ identical flags to $7$ different flagpoles if each flagpole has at least one flag is the number of solutions of the below equation in the positive integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of $6$ addition signs in the $9$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $10$ ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 +1 +1 +1 1 +1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 3$, $x_3 = 1$, $x_4 = 1$, $x_5 = 1$, $x_6 = 1$, $x_7 = 1$.  Thus, the number of solutions of the equation in the positive integers is
$$\binom{9}{6}$$
Since the order of the flags(and flags are different) on a flagpole is relevant, we multiply this result by $10!$ to obtain
$$\binom{9}{6} \cdot 10! = 84 \cdot 10! =  304,819,200$$
ways of placing $10$ different flags on $7$ different flagpoles if the order of the flags is relevant and each flagpole flies at least one flag.

Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Could you clarify "equation 1 in the positive integers", and that the flags are all distinct and why all $10!$ arrangements count? Otherwise yours is the best one.

Comment: @obscurans The number of ways of placing 6 addition signs in 9 gaps is the number of solutions of the equation.

Comment: *What* exactly is "equation 1"?

Comment: @obscurans Sorry. I meant the equation with all the 1s

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by looking at how many ways we can place $7$ of our $10$ flags on our $7$ poles, so that each pole gets exactly one flag. The first pole can have any of the $10$ flags, then the next pole can have any of the remaining $9$, then the next can have $8$, and so on, giving us a total number of $\dfrac{10!}{(10-7)!} = 604$ $800$ possible ways to give each pole a flag.

Now, given each of these possible ways to put $7$ flags on $7$ poles, let's find how many orders of the $10$ flags on $7$ poles we get. When we place the $3$ remaining flags, we have a few choices we can make: we can either place them such that each flag is on their own, such that two flags are placed together, or such that all three flags are placed in one group. Let's run through each of these options:

Each on their own: If each flag is placed on their own, then we get the $210$ possibilities you calculated originally: the first flag gets $7$ options, the second gets $6$, and the last gets $5$.

Two at a time: If we place them so that two of them are together, then the group of two gets $7$ choices and the single flag gets $6$. We also have to consider the $6$ possible ways to divide the flags this way: $3$ possible ways to choose the group of $2$, and $2$ ways to order each group of $2$. All together, this gives us $252$ possible orders.

Three at a time: If we place the three flags all together, then we have $7$ choices for where to put them and $6$ choices for the order, yielding $42$ possible orders.

Adding these three cases together gives us $504$ possible ways to place the three remaining flags. This means that the total number of ways that we can put $10$ flags onto $7$ flagpoles such that each flagpole has at least one flag is $604$ $800 \cdot 504 =  304$ $819$ $200$.

Edit: got some feedback from the comments.

Comment: You’re actually **undercounting**, not overcounting: your calculation doesn’t account for the fact that there’s more than one way to add the same $2$ or $3$ flags to a pole after the $7$ bottom flags have already been chosen.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes, sorry. I was thinking of a different problem. In this case there is undercounting.

Comment: I did miss that, thank you. Working on a fix now.

Comment: @StephenDonovan: The easiest way is to use stars and bars to assign flags to poles, making sure to count only the solutions with at least one flag on each pole, and then to multiply by $10!$: each permutation of the $10$ flags corresponds to a different ordered arrangement.

Comment: I'm not aware of that method, would you like to write your own solution with that method? I have a different fix in mind

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have added a solution. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @StephenDonovan We are getting the same final answer but different methods.

Comment: Yeah, your solution definitely makes sense. Very elegantly done, good job

Comment: @Forester: Yes, that’s the one that I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Every pole gets a flag, and you need to distribute 3 extra flags onto poles. That means there's only three cases:

1. One pole gets 4 flags, everything else has just 1.
2. One pole gets 3 flags, one other gets 2 flags, everything else has 1.
3. Three poles get 2 flags each, everything else has 1.

Now, since every single pole is distinguishable, and even the ordering of flags matters on each pole - there are simply no "equivalent cases". Consider ordering the flags by 1. which pole it is flown on; 2. if the same pole, from top to bottom. *Every single way* of ordering them is distinct.

So, for case 1, there is really just "pick one pole to have the 4 flags", and then all $10!$ ways of ordering the flags on the poles counts. That's just $7\cdot10!$.

Extending through the cases, the answer is simply just $\left(\binom{7}{1}+\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{1}+\binom{7}{3}\right)\cdot10!$ and done.